# Getting all Content Editor web part details who are using Custom Script using Powershell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, powershell, jslink, content-editor-web-part

I want to find out all the Content editor web part details who are using Custom Script, JSlink  using SharePoint Power Shell.

Please help me on this
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below PowerShell script:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   Returns a list of pages for a specific webapplication which contain CEWP's with script.
    
.DESCRIPTION
   Returns a list of pages for a specific webapplication which contain CEWP's with script.
    
.NOTES
   File Name: Get-CEWPWithScript.ps1
   Version  : 1.0
    
.PARAMETER WebApplication
   Specifies the URL of the Web Application.
    
.EXAMPLE
   PS > .\Get-CEWPWithScript.ps1 -WebApplication http://intranet.westeros.local
 
   Description
   -----------
   Returns all Content Editor Web Parts which contains Javascript on the http://intranet.westeros.local webapplication
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
   [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$false,HelpMessage="Specifies the URL of the Web Application.")] 
   [string]$WebApplication
)
 
function Get-CEWP([string]$url)
{
   $manager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($url, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
   $webParts = $manager.WebParts
   if ($webParts.Count -ne 0)
   {
      foreach ($webPart in $webParts)
      {
         if ($webPart.GetType() -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart])
         {
            if ($webPart.ContentLink.Length -gt 0)
            {
               # Check file in ContentLink for script tags
               $file = $web.GetFile($webPart.ContentLink)
               $data = $file.OpenBinary()
               $encode = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
               $contents = $encode.GetString($data)
               if ($contents.ToLower().Contains("<script>"))
               {
                   Write-Output "$($web.Url)/$url (CONTENTLINK)"
               }
               break
            }
 
            if ($webPart.Content.InnerText.Contains("<script>"))
            {
               Write-Output "$($web.Url)/$url (HTML)"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
 
# Load the SharePoint PowerShell snapin if needed
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
   Write-Host "Loading the SharePoint PowerShell snapin..."
   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}   
    
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication $WebApplication -EA SilentlyContinue
if ($SPWebApp -eq $null)
{
   Write-Error "$WebApplication is not a valid SharePoint Web application. Aborting execution!"
}
else
{
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Please wait... gathering data."
   $sites = $SPWebApp.Sites
   foreach ($site in $sites)
   {
      try
      {
         $webs = $site.AllWebs
         foreach ($web in $webs)
         {
            try
            {
               # For publishingwebs, check all publishingpages
               if ([Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::IsPublishingWeb($web))
               {
                  $pubweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
                  $pages = $pubweb.GetPublishingPages()
                  foreach($page in $pages)
                  {
                     Get-CEWP -url $page.Url
                  }
               }
                    
               # Libraries and lists have views and forms which can contain webparts... let's get them also
               $lists = $web.GetListsOfType("DocumentLibrary") | ? {$_.IsCatalog -eq $false}
               foreach ($list in $lists)
               {
                  # Check the views
                  $views = $list.Views
                  foreach ($view in $views)
                  {
                     Get-CEWP -url $view.Url
                  }
                        
                  # Check the forms
                  $forms = $list.Forms
                  foreach ($form in $forms)
                  {
                     Get-CEWP -url $form.Url
                  }
               }
            }
            catch {}
            finally { $web.Dispose() }      
         }
      }
      catch {}
      finally { $site.Dispose() }
   }
}
```

Reference:

[Finding CEWP’s with script in your SharePoint sites](http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/sharepoint/finding-cewps-with-script-in-your-sharepoint-sites/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply